# Sort optional fields in Lucene.net

Tags: search, lucene, indexing, lucene.net

I have a Lucene index which:

- **always** contains field *Title*
- **may** contain field *Tag* (depending on data that's being indexed)

I have a requirement to sort search results by Title *and* Tag fields. At the moment, if none of the documents in the index contain *Tag* field, the search throws an `SystemException`: "field "Tag" does not appear to be indexed".

I am aware this behaviour is by design.
Is there a way to tell Lucene to optionally sort by Tag field if it exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You have to implement a custom sort on the search results

Answer (score 1):

What I'd do here is add another field that is concatenated title and tags and then sort by that -- should get you what you want and you'll still be able to ride the lucene rails.